# Error - The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to GET all_details of Employee from API, and the details provided me for access the data are UserName ,Password ,API key ,Resource ,Parameters

Resource (GET employees/ ) && Parameters (• all_details (boolean) - For large queries, data is limited to important information. By passing this argument the api will return all data for each record.
•   limit (integer) - Limits the number of records returned.
•   offset (integer) - Offsets the start of the collection by the given number of records.
)

I tried to execute this code but i am getting 401 error, I am new to this service please help me.

Here is the code

```
var request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(@"https://api.midenity.com/api/v1.1/");
        request.Timeout = 1000;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers.Add("api-key", "asdf@1234");
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password");
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        try
        {
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    var reader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                    textBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
        {
            textBox1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

Comment: What is this `api.midenity.com`? Is it developed by you or you are calling a third party authentication api? Do you have the right credential username and password for this api?

Comment: api.midenity.com is developed by third party with authentication api

Comment: and yes i have right credential api key, username and password as well, Please help me

Comment: This is Unauthorized error, I think you need to confirm with the third party. If you send request with credential from PostMan, will you receive the same error?